# string variable shows wrong length

Tags: php

So I have a function that gets some string variables from a form (after the form is submitted), then runs a query using those variables  and returns lines of results.
I have several conditions that work fine, except for one and I can't figure out what's wrong.
When I print out the query and run it in phpMyadmin - it works just fine (returns 3 rows for example), but it doesn't run on the page (shows that 0 rwos are returned).
One thing that I have noticed is that when I do var_dump it gives the correct type (string) but wrong length. trim doesn't make any difference.
So fo example

```
$name2 = "John Doe";
var_dump($name1);
var_dump($name2);
```

The name2 returns  string(8)
But when for name1 it returns string(9), even though name1 is also "John Doe" - I have no idea what that extra character is.
That variable is coming from a form, from a select element. Select is populated from a table. I trim resulting POST value before assigning to name1. Character encoding is the same for the table where names in select element are coming from and table on which I run a query.
All other variables from the form are passing fine and query runs correctly if I don't add the name. Again, if I print out the query (with name condition included) and copy and paste into phpMyAdmin - it runs just fine.
I'm going crazy here.

Comment: what's `$name1` and your code at all? Be more specific.

Comment: As I said in the post it's John Doe as well. It shows the length plus 1 char.

Comment: It's not only 'John Doe' may be there is some invisible/special character. Can you give use the the output of `echo "|" . $name1 . "|";`?

Comment: Give more code please,You have a mistake somewhere. I bet that if you do this: `$name1 = "John Doe"; $name2 = "John Doe";var_dump($name1);var_dump($name2);` you'll get the same length.

Answer (score 2):

At a first look this can be a character encoding issue.

I don't know what happens (there are to few data to me) but I would suggest to scan the two string (the actual one and the string you are waiting for) and have the chars returned for further investigation:

```
function compare($s1, $s2) {
    $i = 0;
    while ($s1[$i]) {
        if ($s1[$i] != $s2[$i]) return array($s1[$i], $s2[$i]);
        $i++;
    }
}

var_dump(compare($name1, $name2));
```

Edit:
Maybe a couple of php lines will help me to better explain what I mean. The strings look equals but they are not as the A in the second one is a [Cyrillic Character](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0410/index.htm) that is rendered on the
screen as an A (but counts two bytes, hence the different strlen)

```
 mb_internal_encoding('UTF-8');
 $plainOldAscii = 'TASTE';
 $aBitOfCyrillic = html_entity_decode('T&#1040;STE', ENT_NOQUOTES,'UTF-8');
 echo "$plainOldAscii  -> " . strlen($oldPlainAscii)  
    . " -> "                  . mb_strlen($oldPlainAscii)
    . "\n$aBitOfCyrillic -> " . strlen($aBitOfCyrillic) 
    . " -> "                  . mb_strlen($aBitOfCyrillic)
    . "\n";
```

Comment: It seems like it was an encoding issue, but I have no idea why - I've posted my solution above. I've printed out every name and then out it back in the table by copying and pasting from the screen. The thing is - encoding was definitely the same in every table, type was the same (varchar) and there was no visible difference in names in the db table with names and the ones printed out. No extra spaces in the middle, beginning or end, or anything like that  But after I've removed existing names and put in ones from the screen, queries run fine and function returns expected results.

Comment: @AR. I've added an example to better explain what I think is happening

Answer (score 0):

Possibly your $name1 is something like "John Doe " with a space at the end or a space at the beginning...

Comment: He stated that the input is trimmed

Answer (score 0):

Ok, it was a database issue.
Still have no idea how is that possible - there were no extra spaces in names in the db or strange characters. Encoding is correct and the same thoughout the db, but printing out names on the screen and then copying and inserting back in the names table fixed it. Even though there was no visible difference. Weird.